# angular, django and csrf

Tags: django, angularjs, csrf, django-rest-framework

from http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http , it says we should set default headers to include the token, so i am following it.

my code goes something like this

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $cookies){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: HomeCtrl
            }).
            when('/game/:gameId/shortlist/create',{
                templateUrl: '/partials/create-shortlist.html',
                controller: CreateShortlistCtrl
            }).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);

myapp.run(function($rootScope, $http, $cookies, $httpProvider){
    $http.get('/api/get-current-user').success(function(data){
        $rootScope.current_user = data;
        $rootScope.current_team = $rootScope.current_user.team;
    });
    $http.get('/api/get-current-season').success(function(data){
        $rootScope.current_season = data;
    });
    $rootScope.csrf_token = $cookies.csrftoken;
    console.log($httpProvider.defaults.headers.common);
    //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
});
```

as you can see, i have applied multiple approaches but am unable to set header with csrf token. the two errors i have encountered are

> Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <-
>   $httpProvider

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use AngularJS 1.1.3 or newer you can use `xsrfHeaderName` and `xsrfCookieName`:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $cookies){
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    ...
```

See [$location](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24http) in 1.1.3 the documentation.

Comment: better method. as it passes the unit/e2e tests with protractor

Answer (score 15):

You can only use the `$httpProvider` in the config-method. But the problem is that you cannot use `$cookies` in the config-method. There only `$cookiesProvider` is supported.
That is described (a bit) in the [Module Loading & Dependencies](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) section.

What you can do is set the headers at runtime as suggested in the [angularjs.org docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

So to make your example work, you can do the following:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: HomeCtrl
            }).
            when('/game/:gameId/shortlist/create',{
                templateUrl: '/partials/create-shortlist.html',
                controller: CreateShortlistCtrl
            }).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);

myapp.run(function($rootScope, $http, $cookies){
    // set the CSRF token here
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;

    $http.get('/api/get-current-user').success(function(data){
        $rootScope.current_user = data;
        $rootScope.current_team = $rootScope.current_user.team;
    });
    $http.get('/api/get-current-season').success(function(data){
        $rootScope.current_season = data;
    });
});
```

And don't forget to include the `angular-cookies.js` file in your html-file!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small lib that could make this more simple https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-csrf-cross-domain