# How to set $httpProvider default headers from my app config in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set my

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $cookie.auth_token;
```

in my .config section of my app, but it doesn't seem like I can access the document/cookies just yet? Is there a better place to set this?

I'm doing this because I'm storing my users auth_token in a cookie so they don't need to login every time they use my mobile app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [$http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#crosssiterequestforgeryxsrfprotection):

> ... Angular provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR
>   requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie called
>   XSRF-TOKEN and sets it as the HTTP header X-XSRF-TOKEN.
>
> ... To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a
>   JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP
>   GET request

So if you set your CSRF token in cookie name XSRF-TOKEN then no adjustments are needed on Angular side. and your code should work as is.

Comment: Not working for me. I can confirm my token is there via web inspector but still getting the same error. However, this is manifested in a Rails error "WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" So is maybe it's because it's not creating a CSRF token at all, but a XSRF one?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Check out the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663574/angular-django-and-csrf