# Posting form with CSRF token in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies, csrf

I want to post a form with CSRF token using angular. I have a working code in Jquery but not able to figure out how the same can be converted to Angular.

```
$("body").on("click", "#logout", function() {

              var url = "http://localhost/lab/theapp/api/user/logout.json";     



            try {
             $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 type: 'post',
                 dataType: 'json',

                 beforeSend: function (request) {

                   request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $.cookie('token'));
                 },



                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert('button_logout - failed to logout');
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
                 },
                 success: function (data) {
                   alert("You have been logged out.");

                 }
             });
            }
            catch (error) { alert("button_logout - " + error); }
            return false;




        });
```

Also how do I access/set cookie using angular?

Comment: $http (to replace $.ajax), which also allows you to set request headers: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http For cookies, use the ngCookies module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Comment: Those are a couple of leads. I'd be happy to help with more specifics if you try something, run into some concrete problems, and then provide some Angular code to look at.

Comment: Thanks. Marck, I will be trying it once back in office where rest of code is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set $httpProvider default headers from my app config in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259913/how-to-set-httpprovider-default-headers-from-my-app-config-in-angularjs)