# Single page angular app with django auth

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

So basically I started to work on a single page webapp using Angular. I use Django + Tastypie as a backend which provide an API that is consumed by Angular.

I have no trouble to protect my API by using [Tastypie Auth](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html).

But I want that only members can access to the web app. How to do that with Angular? I would like to use Django session so I can continue to use SessionAuthentification from Tastypie but I have really no idea how to proceed...

in fact, I would like to have my angular webapp completely independent from Django. Which mean I can't use Django to login a user and then make Django render a template with angular.

I found a lot of resources on the internet regarding dealing with user auth with angular but still i'm a little bit lost. I'm afraid to do something really bad with a lot of security issues...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but got a Csrf issue when trying to post to /user/login/ :(

Comment: Make sure you have `csrf_token` in your template and check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17329667/538471

Comment: Ok so I managed to use this method. I had an issue with an already existing url /login/. Now I am looking for the best solution to logout a user based on it's session Id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399152/how-to-logout-a-user-using-its-session-id

Comment: start a new question.

Comment: Already done with the link i send in my previous message ;)