# How to logout a user using it's session id

Tags: django, django-models

I followed this method to have an API to login a user using Tastypie and Django Auth: [Login with Tastypie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770501/how-can-i-login-to-django-using-tastypie)

Once I log a user in through Tastypie, I received a session id I store in my app.

Now I want to logout the suer when he use the logout button -> how can I logout a user based on it's session id ? I wanted to use logout() function but it uses a request containing a user object as parameter and I don't have it with my javascript app.

I tried to find in the code how was made the logout function but it flush the sessionbase and I don't have such an object.

My idea: getting session based on session id and delete the row:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
s = Session.objects.get(pk='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
s.delete()
```

Is it a good idea ?

Comment: In your previous question I gave you a link to an example with both login and logout. That logout method is not working for you?

Comment: No because logout example in this solution use request object and with a single page app, this request objet does not contain a user object.

Comment: But you do authenticate the user when they log in. So all you have to do is destroy that session. That logout method does that.